# Compiler error when calling toArray

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
scala> def a[A](b:Seq[A]) = b.toArray
<console>:7: error: could not find implicit value 
                    for evidence parameter of type ClassManifest[A]
       def a[A](b:Seq[A]) = b.toArray
                              ^
```

What is the problem here? And how can I work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have to do is to specify the returnable type, this will work (for scala < 2.8):

```
def a[A](b:Seq[A]):Array[A] = b.toArray
```

Due to the new Collections framework which had to do special kind of conversion in order to handle Arrays like Collections see [Fighting bit rot](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2009/2338/pdf/09005.OderskyM.2338.pdf) page 448, we have to tell about the high-order type, and it's the meaning of `ClassManifest` which tells about the class (there is a `Manifest` that is wider).

So both examples below are valid (more information here [Collections API Explained](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html)):

```
 def a[A](b:Seq[A])(implicit m:ClassManifest[A]):Array[A] = b.toArray

 def a[A:ClassManifest](b:Seq[A]):Array[A] = b.toArray
```

Comment: So I added for >= 2.8, and why it should be given such weird extra information to the compiler

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> def a[A : ClassManifest](b:Seq[A]) = b.toArray
a: [A](b: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$1: ClassManifest[A])Array[A]

scala>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a view bound to provide it with the manifest:

```
def a[A: ClassManifest](b:Seq[A]) = b.toArray
```